# How to connect to my network

Tags: wireless, networking

I am a complete newbie to Linux/Ubuntu.  I experimented with Zorin 6.2, which immediately found my wifi network and connected to it, but I thought I would be better off to get the latest Ubuntu LTS distro (14.04).  Unfortunately, Ubuntu has not picked up my network, and the manual setup is very complex.  Could someone please direct me to step-by-step instructions for getting connected to my network?

FYI, I chose Ubuntu because it was said to be friendly for first-time Linux users, switching over from Windows.  So far, I am quite disappointed.  I'm an advanced Windows user, but decided to switch because of MS' support policies and attempts to dominate the market.  I'd really like to make Ubuntu work for me, but so far, it's been a total zero.  I did an on-line search and found some other poor soul like myself, who was basically told that he was a dumb ass for not being able to figure out his problem for himself.  I hope this is not the mindset of the rest of the Linux community.

Comment: Generally, that is not our mindset. We strive to be polite and respectful. First, let's identify your wireless device. Please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run lspci -nn. Pick out your wireless and then edit your question to add the details; then we'll proceed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a whole boatload of problems with the wireless in ubuntu, it isn't just an isolated problem nor is it something that automatically makes you an idiot if you don't understand. If it is a card that ubuntu does not have open source driver alternatives, then it is not by default supported. A famous example is the broadcom series. If it is a broadcom card, you can try pressing ctrl+alt+f1 then typing in (while connected to a network via ethernet) "sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source". I will try and find the page that goes into detail the procedure for some of the more specific cards, but you can try that to start

Comment: bcmwl-kernel-source is not correct for all Broadcoms; sorry.

Comment: I know that, I've just had this work on 80% of my devices, I was finding the page that has great detail on the matter that also INCLUDES the procedures for other cards

Comment: Why ask the guy to install something that may need to be purged later? Just ask for the device identity and give the correct answer once.

Comment: well I'm sorry I gave an answer that was a little less than optimal while I have 4 or 5 people waiting for my input on something on xda-developers